# ExtJS how to effetively store values common for several functions in a single controller

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In view I have 4 buttons. In controller I have references to those buttons. There is the complicated logic to enable/disable each button, unfortunatelly scattered into several function - event listeners. Each listener has different parameters. Example:

```
listener1: function(data1) {
    button1.setDisabled(data1.status = ProcessStatus.running);
    button2.setDisabled(data1.status = ProcessStatus.running);
}

listener2: function(upload) {
    button2.setDisabled(!upload.enabled);
}
```

I want to refactor the code: create single function in controller `updateButtonsState`. Then each listener would set somewhere a value and call `updateButtonsState()` without parameters.

```
listener2: function(upload) {
    saveUploadEnabled(upload.enabled);
    updateButtonsState();
    button2.setDisabled(!upload.enabled);
}

updateButtonsState: function() {
    var uploadEnabled = loadUploadEnabled();
    var data1StatusProcessRunning = loadData1Status();
    button1.setDisabled(data1StatusProcessRunning);
    button2.setDisabled(uploadEnabled || data1StatusProcessRunning);
}
```

How to implement `save*` and `load*` methods? Where should I store those data?

Comment: Can you please create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) and explain your goal clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major possibilities: You can store the state directly in the controller, or use a closure to create a "private" variable and not expose it to anything except the getter/setter functions that are your interface.

controllers have an [`init`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Controller.html#method-init) method that you could use for the closure:

```
init: function(application) {
    var myPrivateVariable = {};
    this.saveUploadEnabled = function(uploadEnabled) {
         myPrivateVariable.uploadEnabled = uploadEnabled;
    }
    this.saveStatus = function(status) {
         myPrivateVariable.status = status;
    }
    this.updateButtonState = function() {
        button1.setDisabled(myPrivateVariable.status == ProcessStatus.Running || !myPrivateVariable.uploadEnabled)
    }
}
```